# Php array returns null?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have php file which reads a file and puts it's contents in specific arrays. This php file is a file on it's own. So I included it on another page. When I want to access one of the arrays on the other site, the output is "array(0) { }". The var_dump on the file below, however returns a full array with all 6 items(as expected).

Here my php file:

```
<?php

$englishTranslationsList = array();
$germanTranslationsList = array();
$timestampList = array();
$noteList = array();

function extractTranslationsFromFile($file){

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle){

        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

            $notelist[] = $line;

            $lineContent = substr($line, 3, strlen($line) - 1);

            switch(substr($line, 0, 3)):

            case "de:":  $germanTranslationsList[] = $lineContent;  break;
            case "en:":  $englishTranslationsList[] = $lineContent; break;
            case "ts:":  $timestampList[] = $lineContent; break;

            default: break;

            endswitch;

        }

        fclose($handle);

    }else{

        echo "<script>alert('ERROR')</script>";

    } 

    echo var_dump($germanTranslationsList);

}

?>
```

On the site where I included it, I used

```
<p><?php echo var_dump($germanTranslationsList); ?></p>
```

Which just shows an empty array as said above...
What have I done wrong? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: remove `echo` from `var_dump`

Comment: Changes nothing...

Comment: validate if you have value in $notelist[] array

Comment: You need to bring the global variables into scope using the [`global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

Comment: put here your sample german Translation file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the global variables into the function's scope using the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword:

```
<?php

$englishTranslationsList = array();
$germanTranslationsList = array();
$timestampList = array();
$noteList = array();

function extractTranslationsFromFile($file) {
    global $englishTranslationsList;
    global $germanTranslationsList;
    global $timestampList;
    global $noteList;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Warning

When you include B.php in A.php, you should careful about **the file path** that you define in B.php.
So, I guess you defined some relative file path.

## Example

**Directory_stucture**

```
.
├── A.php
└── dir
    ├── a.txt
    └── B.php
```

**A.php**

```
require_once('dir/B.php');
```

**B.php**

```
$handle = fopen("a.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($handle,filesize("a.txt"));
fclose($handle);
```

**a.txt**

```
Hello, world!
```

**Result**

[image]

Run B.php works fine, print 'Hello, world!'
But if you run A.php ,it print 'Unable to open file!'

## Reason

When run B.php, `fopen()` search 'a.txt' in the dir that B.php live.
But when run A.php, `fopen()` search 'a.txt' in the dir that A.php live.

## Advice

Use absolute file path instead of relative.